# How can i upgrade pip's setup tools

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pip, dockerfile, ansible-awx

I am quite new to Docker/Python and trying to update an existing AWX's Docker Image's Dockerfile to ensure that i have the latest versions of the following packages in `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/poolmanager.py
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/retry.py
```

Following is my environment info:

> Docker version 19.03.3, build a872fc2f86
>
> Docker Base Image: centos:latest

The Dockerfile in which i am making changes for this is available [here](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/installer/roles/image_build/templates/Dockerfile.j2).

From what i have read from multiple posts/blogs so far, this should normally be updated by a simple:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

but when i run this, i am getting the following (and it shows a different path which includes `local` in the path.

```
bash-4.4# pip3 install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (19.3.1)
```

I have even tried the following but this didn't help:

```
bash-4.4# python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

bash-4.4# pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (42.0.2)
```

**This is how the above changes were applied in the Dockerfile**

In this Dockerfile, i have added the following lines **after** line 124 in the Dockerfile to update pip packages:

```
RUN yum update -y
RUN pip2 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

**Snapshot of required sections from Dockerfile**

```
FROM centos:latest
USER root

# sync with installer/roles/image_build/templates/Dockerfile.j2
RUN dnf -y update && \
  dnf -y install epel-release 'dnf-command(config-manager)' && \
  dnf module -y enable 'postgresql:10' && \
  dnf config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools && \
  .
  .
  .
  ansible \
  python3-devel \
  python3-libselinux \
  python3-pip \
  python3-psycopg2 \
  python3-setuptools \
  dnf-utils

ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/v0.14.0/tini /tini
RUN chmod +x /tini

RUN python3 -m ensurepip && pip3 install virtualenv
RUN pip3 install supervisor

ADD Makefile /tmp/Makefile
RUN mkdir /tmp/requirements
ADD requirements/requirements_ansible.txt \
    requirements/requirements_ansible_uninstall.txt \
    requirements/requirements_ansible_git.txt \
    requirements/requirements.txt \
    requirements/requirements_tower_uninstall.txt \
    requirements/requirements_git.txt \
    /tmp/requirements/
RUN cd /tmp && VENV_BASE="/var/lib/awx/venv" make requirements_awx requirements_ansible_py3
.
.
.
RUN echo "{{ awx_version }}" > /var/lib/awx/.tower_version
COPY {{ awx_sdist_file }} /tmp/{{ awx_sdist_file }}
RUN OFFICIAL=yes /var/lib/awx/venv/awx/bin/pip install /tmp/{{ awx_sdist_file }}
```

Somehow the changes are not getting reflected in the correct path. Can someone please suggest how to update the packages inside: `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

Comment: You need to include the Dockerfile in the question itself, not behind an external link.  If it's really 124 lines long, try trimming it down to a [mcve] that only contains what's needed to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: I'm also a little unclear as to what your specific issue is.  You're pointing at files inside `pip`'s vendor tree; why do those specific files need to be updated, and are you trying to update them to something different than what pip's packaging includes?

Comment: @DavidMaze: Yes, since the file was too big, i thought of specifying a link to actual file. I will try to edit the question to add specific sections.
Actually, i would like to update all the files/packages inside that directory. I specified these specific files because our vulnerability scan has picked these files and the recommended action is to upgrade them to the latest version.